# Can you use .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate to generate files that are not located in the same folder as swagger-codegen-cli?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

Using `java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l typescript-angular -i .\swagger.json`, I can turn ".\swagger.json" into a typescript-angular file. However, the .json file **must** be in the same folder as the `swagger-codegen-cli`, which is impractical when you have many files to convert (You have to manually download and move every file). I've scoured the web, but haven't been able to find a practical solution. Is there a way to do this? Am I able to integrate swagger-codegen in such a way that I can "mass produce" files? I know I can change the output directory (-o) but that isn't what I'm looking for. Say I have a folder called "scripts" where I've got a lot of .json files. Am I able to call `swagger-codegen-cli generate` on any file inside of that folder, even if `swagger-codegen-cli` is located in a different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-i` argument expects a fully-qualified or relative path to an OpenAPI file, or an URL where that file is located. That is, the file does not have to be in the same folder as the Swagger Codegen CLI.

Examples:

```
# The file is in the current working folder
-i swagger.json
-i ./swagger.json

# The file is in a subfolder of the current working folder
-i sub/folder/swagger.json
-i ./sub/folder/swagger.json

# Relative path to a file in another folder
-i ../../path/to/swagger.json

# Absolute path - Windows
-i C:/path/to/swagger.json

# Absolute path - *nix
-i ~/path/to/swagger.json

# URL
-i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
```